# Iptables comment module not installed

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, kernel-modules

I want to use -m comment --comment "message" in my iptables rule but do not have the module loaded. Through some searching, the module I need for this is "ipt_comment" but I do not have this installed. How can I make this happen?

My version of Iptables is 1.4.21

/sbin/modprobe --list returns nothing

/sbin/lsmod is empty as well.

Im using Ubuntu 12.04.1 server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are on an OpenVZ based VPS. You cannot install modules on such a VPS.

You have two options:

1. You can ask the host to install the module for you.
2. You can switch to a different VPS which is not based on OpenVZ.

Use the `virt-what` command to confirm what type of VPS you have.

Comment: Yes you are correct as to OpenVZ based and thanks for your answer. I'm gonna wait for any other responses otherwise I'll check this off :)